# Can ESC be programmed to run full throttle only on one side of a quadcopter?

Tags: quadcopter

Can ESC in quads be programmed in such a way that only one side has throttle and no throttle at all on the other? This would cause the quad to flip I suppose?

With that, is there a way we can program the controller to like trigger a switch when we want the quad to flip? Because I was thinking of doing a waterproof quad. So initially, it flies in the air normally with the 4 channel, and then I set it to float on water. After that, I was thinking of maybe triggering a switch on the controller so that this time it's just going to flip and nothing else. After it flips, I would trigger the switch back to normal operation. Is that possible?

Comment: Of course. Why not? What issues do you anticipate this would cause?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this, but you don't need a switch to do so; just command the quad copter to [fly inverted](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=92&v=VIkqqVr_u9U&t=1m20s). That video demos variable pitch rotors specifically, but [those aren't required](http://hackaday.com/2013/11/26/quadcopters-go-inverted-by-reversing-their-motors/) for inverted flight. You can [buy off the shelf units](http://www.rcdronearena.com/2015/05/31/udi-u27-free-loop-quadcopter-launch-price/) capable of flying upside down for relatively cheap and modify as you see fit.

Alternatively, if you're just looking to be able to fly in the air or float, you can just build the quad copter with the [motors pointing down to begin with](http://diydrones.com/forum/topics/can-quadcopter-motors-be-mounted-upside-down).